# What is the difference between target="font" and target="pattern" in fontconfig?

Tags: fonts

I am trying to understand why some of tests in my `fonts.conf` work with `<match target="pattern">` (the default), another ones with `<match target="font">`, and not at all otherwise. For example:

```
<match>
    <test name="family"><string>monospace</string></test>        
    <edit name="family"><string>Cousine</string></edit>
</match>

<match>
    <test name="family"><string>Cousine</string></test>
    <test name="pixelsize" compare="more"><double>17.5</double></test>
    <edit name="family" binding="strong"><string>Liberation Mono</string></edit>
</match>

<match target="font">
    <test name="family"><string>Overpass</string></test>        
    <edit name="hintstyle"><const>hintslight</const></edit>
</match>
```

Why is that? I have read the documentation and it only says `If 'target' is set to "font" instead of the default "pattern", then this element applies to the font name resulting from a match rather than a font pattern to be matched.` I do not understand the wording, can someone explain the difference?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From:

https://lists.freedesktop.org/archives/fontconfig/2007-December/002787.html

> Applications typically work like this:
>
> 1. Convert user's font request to a fontconfig pattern;
> 2. Apply fontconfig configuration on it using target="pattern";
> 3. Get a sorted list of fonts matching that pattern from fontconfig. The list is returned as a set of fontconfig patterns itself;
> 4. Choose the font to use (typically the first one having the requested character);
> 5. Apply fontconfig configuration on the font pattern using target="font".
>
> So, what it means is that for example if you want to turn off antialiasing on Bitstream Vera Sans for sizes less than 7.5, you should do that using target="font". If you do it with target="pattern", it will turn off aa for all fonts if the request is Bitstream Vera Sans, regardless of whether you have that font installed or not.
>
> If you want to write fallback rules such that DejaVu Sans be substituted for Bitstream Vera Sans, that's done with target="pattern", because you want to modify the request.

And also from:

https://lists.freedesktop.org/archives/fontconfig/2003-March/000128.html

> Use the font target for all changes to how a particular font is rendered and pattern target for changes in how a font is selected from those available.